# Why doesn't findByIdAndUpdate update the document?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

I have my problem with the following function

```
export function updateLine(req: Request, res: Response) {
    if (!req.params.id || !req.body) return res.status(400).send({ message: 'Client has not sent params' });
    Line.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, async (err, lineUpdated) => {
        console.log("req.params.id", req.params.id)
        console.log("lineUpdated", lineUpdated)
        console.log("req.body", req.body)
        if (err) return res.status(409).send({ message: 'Internal error, probably error with params' });
        if (!lineUpdated) return res.status(404).send({ message: 'Document not found' });
        if (req.params.id !== lineUpdated.id) await Key.updateMany({ 'line': req.params.id }, { 'line': lineUpdated._id }).exec(err => {
            if (err) return res.status(500).send({ message: 'Key Internal Server Error' });
        });
        return res.status(200).send({ data: lineUpdated });
    });
}
```

What I'm trying to do is just update the document `req.params.id` with what contains `req.body`

The responses to the console.log () shown are as follows

```
req.params.id ACCSEH
lineUpdated {
  _id: 'ACCSEH',
  name: 'Accesorios (SEH)',
  started: 2020-04-21T20:25:10.395Z,
  __v: 0
}
req.body { id: 'ACCSEJ', name: 'Accesorios (SEH)' }
```

I am doing something wrong?

I already know that lineUpdated will return the function to me before the change. I mean when I do the query to see the change nothing has changed

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7uCM.png)

Comment: Are you trying to update `_id` ?

Comment: @TheeSritabtim Yep

Comment: 1. The body specified `id` but you wan't to update `_id`. 2. Even if the body is correct, you can't update the `_id`, as mentioned in the answer, as it is used as primary key and is immutable

Comment: Mmm Ok btw. How can I reference for example if I change the _id for idk identifier. How can I reference the identifier part in the User Schema @TheeSritabtim

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean. Can you give a bit more concrete example?

Comment: If you want your identifier to be modifiable and if this is not a production database yet, I suggest you leave _id out of the Schema to let it autogenerate by mongoose. Then you can add a new field as an identifier and you can drop the old data with your defined _id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/):

> The field name _id is reserved for use as a primary key; its value
> must be unique in the collection, is immutable, and may be of any type
> other than an array.

You can not change `_id` field once it is inserted into the collection

Answer (score 0):

When finding and updating by ID you can't give it an ID in the object - you need to give it an object that has some combination of the other items (name, started, _v).